# Makefile for linux kernel module issue

Tags: c, linux, makefile, driver, kernel-module

I'm writing a kernel module which will be a driver for my chinese Arduino.

I've read many guides about it and Makefiles in them are completely different. Some of them just is not working. And I want to understand how and why:)

For example, I have a simple beginner's code:

```
    #define MODULE
    #define __KERNEL__

    #include <module.h> // определения для модуля 
    #include <init.h> // module_init и module_exit
    #include <kernel.h> // printk

    MODULE_AUTHOR("...");
    MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module for linux kernel");

    int module_start() 
    {
        printk("This is a test module startup message\n");
        return 0;
    }

    void module_stop()
    {
        printk("Module is dead\n");
        return;
    }

    module_init(module_start);
    module_exit(module_stop);
```

And also I have a Makefile which I found in manual:

```
    CC=gcc
    MODFLAGS:= -O2 -Wall -DLINUX
    module.o: module.c
    $(CC) $(MODFLAGS) -c module.c
```

So, as I know, my system uses .ko files as a modules. This is the first problem. The second is that this makefile just doesn't work.

When I make, I'm getting the error "missing module.h". But I certainly installed headers. They are in `/usr/src/linux-headers-(3.2.0-4-686-pae)` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-(3.2.0-4-common)`.
There is no module.h in *pae directory, but it is in *common directory(most of the files are there). So, I just can't compile it neither with gcc nor the makefile.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: I advise you to try to build the module by calling `gcc` from the command line. When that works perfectly, you can write a makefile to automate the process.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I don't know how to compile this properly...
I'm getting the error "missing module.h". Compiled with gcc with these parameters (gcc -O2 -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -isystem /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include   -c -o ard_module.o ard_module.c)

Comment: And, yes. I have headers installed in /usr/src by apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Maybe the problem is that my system is x64 and gcc trying to find files in different directory? So, what I should do to fix it?

Comment: Try adding "-I /usr/src" to the `gcc` command.

Comment: It did not help:c
The header files installed by command (apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) ) in two folders: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae and /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common.

So, what command you would use, @Beta, if you need to compile this module?

Comment: Also, don't kow why, but there is small amount of files in pae folder unlike in common folder.

My path to the ~build folder is /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/~build

Comment: If the files are in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae/` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/`, then instead of "-I /usr/src", try "-I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common".

Comment: Okaaay. Used that command "gcc -O2 -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -c -o ard_module.o -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/ ard_module.c". Module.h error disappeared. But new appeared: "In file included from ard_module.c:4:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/module.h:9:24: fatal error: linux/list.h: no such file or directory,
compilation terminated."

Comment: Why did you include `<module.h>` if the compiler does not know where to look? should that be `"module.h"`. By the sound of it, it looks like you're missing a `-I` switch to tell the compiler to look for the explicit directory.

Comment: Hello, @t0mm13b. module.h located in '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux'. Latest command I used to compile my module is 'gcc -O2 -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -c -o ard_module.o -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/ ard_module.c'.It outputs 'In file included from ard_module.c:4:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/module.h:9:24: fatal error: linux/list.h: no such file or directory'. 

Looks like the modules should be compiled in a special way using makefile to avoid dependent paths. Or I don't understand something...

Comment: @kekyc no. You need to specify additional -I for the other directories that the compiler is complaining of. Also, take out the leading slash from the directory path too.

Comment: @t0mm13b, this 'list.h' located in the same directory as 'module.h'. The problem is that 'module.h' includes 'list.h' as '#include <linux/list.h>'.
i.e we tell compiler to find files in '/usr/src/linux-headers-***/include/linux' and after that the files which were found there(module.h) trying to include files with the wrong path - './linux/list.h'
So, I don't know how to fix it without editing paths in the header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "standard Makefile" for a module build is :

```
obj-m    := hello-1.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

( Creating hello-1.ko from hello-1.c )

The only headers used are the ones in /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include/.

And there is no ``module.h´´ : Please enter like `#include <linux/module.h>` ( or asm/module.h ).

---

Comment: Just found that makefile example ~1 hour ago and it solved my problem. But thank you very much too!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the .ko module question. I'm not sure what the question really is.

But as for the missing separator error, this is a common Makefile problem. Commands(the $CC line below) in Makefiles must be preceeded with a tab.

**To fix, simply add a TAB before your $(CC) line like so:**

```
CC=gcc MODFLAGS:= -O2 -Wall -DLINUX 
module.o: module.c 
      $(CC) $(MODFLAGS) -c module.c
 / \ 
  |
  | 
 TAB
```

Comment: Yeah, already found it. The problems now are more stupid and difficult(watch comments) :c